# Can't run tor on Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, tor

I am having trouble running `tor`. I think that I have narrowed down the problem to my `start-tor-browser.desktop` file. I am pretty sure my machine is only reading it as text file and not an executable. There is no option to change it under my file preferences. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that its permissions are set to be executable, in your terminal type:

`chmod +x start-tor-browser.desktop`

Personally, on debian based systems I just use `torbrowser-launcher`, it will also check the signatures for you:

`sudo apt install torbrowser-launcher`

Then:

`torbrowser-launcher`

If you get a `GPG error` then refresh the gpg keys by doing:

`gpg --homedir "$HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/gnupg_homedir/" --refresh-keys --keyserver pgp.mit.edu`

Then execute the launcher once again:

`torbrowser-launcher`